# How to pass a script argument with spaces to Azure CLI task

Tags: azure-devops, azure-cli2

There is an Azure CLI v2 task in one of my Azure DevOps release pipelines. Its `Script Type` is set as *Shell* and `Script Location` is set as *Inline Script*. I am trying to pass a script argument with spaces to an environment variable defined within the script. I am very simple version of my Azure CLI script is below:

```
az container create --resource-group $(resourceGroup) BLA BLA BLA --environment-variables 'DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT'=$1 'ConnectionStrings__MyDatabase'=$2
```

ANd in the Script Arguments section I provide args like this:

```
'$(TargetEnvironment)' `$(ConnectionStrings.MyDatabase)`
```

Single quotes or double quotes, it doesn't matter because the generated `ConnectionStrings__MyDatabase` variable is truncated till the first space. For example instead of "*Server=tcp:dev.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=Employess;*" it is only "*Server=tcp:dev.database.windows.net,1433;Initial*".

Answer (score 0):

***Make sure you add double inverted commas "" in your environment variable for the Azure CLI task to consider the values with space.***

**My Azure Release pipeline variables:-**

```
ConnectionStrings.MyDatabase Server=tcp:dev.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=Employess

TargetEnvironment Development
```

[image]

**My AzureCLITask Inline Script:-**

Script [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az-container-create).

```bash
az container create -g siliconrg --name myapp123 --image mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/aci-helloworld:latest --cpu 1 --memory 1 --environment-variables "TARGET_ENVIRONMENT=$(TargetEnvironment)" "CONNECTION_STRINGS_MYDATABASE=$(ConnectionStrings.MyDatabase)"
```

[image]

**Output:-**

[image]

**Portal:-**

[image]

***I tried the same command from this [**MS Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az-container-create) in Azure Cloud shell with "" commas and it worked, Refer below:-***

> ```bash
> az container create -g siliconrg --name myapp --image
> mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/aci-helloworld:latest --cpu 1 --memory 1
> --environment-variables "Server=tcp:dev.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=Employess;"
> "key= Value 1"
> ```

**Output:-**

[image]

**Portal:-**

[image]